# How to read factors' levels right in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have a big csv file that has 51993 rows and 18 columns. Here is part of the table:

```
head(ddd)
country.of.birth age   sex X2000 X2001 X2002 X2003 X2004 X2005 X2006 X2007
Afghanistan       0    men     0     0     1     2     2     0     1     1
Afghanistan       0  women     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
Afghanistan       1    men     0     2     5     2     3     4     1     1
Afghanistan       1  women     4     1     4     2     3     2     3     2
Afghanistan       2    men     5     0     8     7     7     3     5     3
Afghanistan       2  women     4     8     3     9     4     4     4     3
```

In the main csv file, the columns are: Country of Birth, age, sex, and then years from 2000 to 2014. My questions are why does R put X before each year number?

When I used the str() function, I got:

```
> str(ddd)
'data.frame':   15264 obs. of  18 variables:
$ country.of.birth: Factor w/ 261 levels "0","1","10","103",..: 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 ...
$ age             : Factor w/ 38 levels "","0 ","1 ","10 ",..: 2 2 3 3 14 14 17 17 20 20 ...
$ sex             : Factor w/ 39 levels "","0 ","1 ","10 ",..: 38 39 38 39 38 39 38 39 38 39 ...
$ X2000           : Factor w/ 786 levels "","0","1","10",..: 2 3 2 478 555 478 92 4 205 716 ...
$ X2001           : int  0 1 2 1 0 8 11 8 26 19 ...
$ X2002           : int  1 0 5 4 8 3 13 18 22 15 ...
$ X2003           : int  2 0 2 2 7 9 15 13 23 33 ...
$ X2004           : int  2 1 3 3 7 4 11 15 21 22 ...
$ X2005           : int  0 0 4 2 3 4 10 6 13 16 ...
$ X2006           : int  1 0 1 3 5 4 8 13 20 10 ...
$ X2007           : int  1 0 1 2 3 3 6 7 9 17 ...
$ X2008           : int  0 0 2 0 4 5 4 6 8 9 ...
$ X2009           : int  0 1 1 4 7 3 9 10 11 12 ...
$ X2010           : int  1 1 6 4 8 10 17 10 21 16 ...
$ X2011           : int  0 5 9 6 21 18 16 27 34 24 ...
$ X2012           : int  3 5 5 16 30 22 44 48 46 49 ...
$ X2013           : int  3 0 12 19 24 34 54 46 76 71 ...
$ X2014           : int  2 3 15 3 21 29 37 48 64 62 ...
```

As you notice, sex is factor but with 39 levels whereas it has only two values (men) and (women). Also, year 2000 (X2000 in the table) is a factor with 786 levels and it should have been read as an "int". Why did R read the observable "sex" with this large number of levels and why did it read year 2000 as a factor while it read the others as int (as is the case)?

Edit:
The age column has values of the form: 20-24, 25-30, ... till 85-90. and another category as 90+

Comment: Apparently, "sex" can be blank (""), 0, 1, 10... And for "X2000", you have also blank (""), i.e. a character mixed together with integers.

Comment: use `read.csv(..., stringsAsFactors=F)` to avoid factor variables if you want. Also I think that in R you can't have a column with number name so R puts X to convert it into character

Comment: @AndriyTkachenko you can. Columns can be called anything you like, even `2 + 2`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of `read.table` and its related functions is to make all column names syntactically valid. This means that they can be used without quoting after the `$` operator. However, this behaviour can be changed using the `check.names = FALSE` parameter. This will mean you end up with columns called `2000` etc. To then use those columns with `$` they will need to be backquoted, e.g.

```
ddd$`2000`
```

The same will be true if you want to use these columns with non-standard evaluation, e.g.

```
ggplot(ddd, aes(x = sex, y = `2000`)) + geom_boxplot()
```

For the sex column, there must be entries in the column further down that have numbers in. Check your original
data.

For age, you have trailing spaces in your age column. Either remove these outside R, or you could do something like this:

```
ddd$age <- as.numeric(sub(" +$", "", as.character(ddd$age)))
```

For the 2000 column, it's not clear from your `str` output why it's been read as a factor. By default, empty strings should be regarded as NA and so shouldn't affect the class. You could try (assuming you're now using `check.names = FALSE`):

```
as.character(ddd$`2000`)[is.na(as.numeric(as.character(ddd$`2000`))) & ddd$`2000` != ""]
```

This should print out any elements of the column which are non-blank and non-numeric. It may again be a trailing space issue.

Comment: I tried check.names=F, and it worked. The fact that I will have to use backquotes makes me (for now) stick to the X2000 format. My other questions were caused by some errors in the original data file (as you suggested.) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

X is put in front of the column names because R doesn't allow first character of the column name to be a number (try `data.frame(a = 1:10, "3" = runif(10))`.

Age is a factor because you have bins and what you observe is expected behavior. R doesn't handle intervals as numeric, but as factor.

Sex variable is weird and given currently available data, I would say the variable represents something other than sex, in at least part of the dataset. Has the dataset been stitched together? Perhaps there was a mistake in copy/pasting. See `levels(ddd$sex)` to disentangle all possible levels.

Comment: I used cat to "stitch" the big file as: `cat file2.csv >> file1.csv`, then `cat file3 >> file1` for all the 5 csv files I have.
I inspected the file again, and I could see some errors in the sex columns which I corrected. That's all for now, thank you.

Comment: Are they absolutely identical in all respects, @FaizLotfy?

Comment: @FaizLotfy Please check if there are any shifts in column and if this corresponds to any of the files.

Comment: I did. They were identical except for the contents. After generating the big file, I noticed the following:
In the age column, the word "years" was after every number in the column. This caused a distortion. I generated the big file again, but this time I did it manually, I copied every file and pasted it below the previous one in a csv file which I opened in LibreOffice. Before I save the file I search for the word "years" and removed it. After saving the file and opening it again, I noticed that the distortion has disappeared.

Comment: @FaizLotfy told you. :)